# A question about ultimate computation capability

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, quantum-computer

If we consider the physical limit of computational capability of a system with average energy $E$, then

(1) According to Margolus and Levitin, a quantum system with average energy $E$ takes time at least $∆t = \pi\hbar/2E$ to evolve to an orthogonal state (a direct result from uncertainty relation).

(2) If the system has an entropy of $S=k_BN$, then we can say there are $2^N$ orthogonal states and each orthogonal state encodes N bits of information.

Question:
Then in time ∆t, a state can evolve to another orthogonal state, and we in fact carry out an operation on $N$ bits.

Should the computational capability be written as $N/∆t  \tilde= E*N$, which is the number of bit operations can be achieved in 1 second? And the number of operation per bit per second is just given by $E$?

But in Llyod's paper he mentioned that "the number of operations per bit per second that our ultimate laptop can perform is given by $E/N$".

I am confused, since it takes a fixed time $∆t$ to evolve between two orthogonal states, so a higher entropy should mean a higher computational capability since now in each step we are working parallelly on $N$ bits. Why Llyod will compute 'the number of operations per bit per second' by dividing $N$?

Which result is wrong?

Comment: Could you give a reference to (1)? As it is written, it is invalid since measurable quantities cannot depend on the value of total energy, only on differences of energies.

Comment: @JánLalinský Yes, you are absolutely right. E should be the 'spread of energy'. I think their result is a limit w.r.t. all possible configurations of the system. My point is the entropy part, i.e., the number of bit operations in 1 second should be proportional to the entropy N as N/∆t or fixed by ∆t as 1/∆t?

Comment: @JánLalinský Please refer to wiki at "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margolus%E2%80%93Levitin_theorem" and reference there.  Related paper: "The maximum speed of dynamical evolution"